# Who is Supreme Brahman?

Tags: shiva, krishna, upanishads, devi, nirguna

In many Upanishad's such as the Skanda, Ganapati and Ganesha Upanishads, the principle deities of that Upanishad are proclaimed as the supreme Supreme Brahman but how can more than one deity be the Supreme Brahman?

Comment: Rg veda 1.164.46 - ekam sat vipra bahudha vadanti 'truth is one, men call it variously'